# SQOOP - password-file option closes the filesystem reference causing java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I'm using Sqoop 1.4.3-cdh4.3.0.  When I run sqoop using the `-password-file` option I get an exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:565)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.close(DFSInputStream.java:589)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.close(LineReader.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.close(LineRecordReader.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.close(MapTask.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
2013-11-01 20:32:43,471 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
```

Looking at their [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.sqoop/sqoop/1.4.3-cdh4.3.0/org/apache/sqoop/util/CredentialsUtil.java) it looks like they're closing the filesystem handle (fetchPasswordFromFlie).  I'm thinking that's why I get the exception above, because when I use clear-case password it works fine.

I am not sure what I can do to resolve this issue.  I've seen several posts that suggest enabing   `fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache`   But I don't know what impact this will have on performance, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using oozie, so in oozie I set the job property `fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache`.  Solved the issue.

Luckily for this job none of our mappers use the fs.  I think if did use fs (`fs = FileSystem.get(conf)`) then we might have had to go through and make sure that each one of those fs are closed (since each time we'd call `get` it would return a new instance).